# Clang - changing linker

Tags: linker, clang, llvm, linker-errors

I am trying to compile/link a program using Clang but its defaulting to using MSVC's link.exe. I am trying to override this and change the linker being used to LD.

I am adding this into my compilation command: "link-fuse=ld" (I have tried replacing ld with a path to the actual executable) and receive this error:

LINK: fatal error: LNK1181: cannot open input file "ink-fuse=ld.lib"

Notice that the "l" from link is being peeled off. How can I change the linker Clang is using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct flag is `-fuse-ld=ld`. See how they illustrate the use of lld in a similar way: https://lld.llvm.org/#using-lld